# What reporting tool/library do java programmer use often?

Tags: java, reporting

I am new to reporting.

I have to generate a report that:

- to display in a webpage
- to display in pdf
- to display in word/excel

The report are supposed to be generated **from database** but in different views(html/pdf/word/excel).

**Each view may have a bit differences.** For example, html has a company icon and header on the top. Pdf has company name header on each page. Excel has no header at all.

I heard `BIRT` and `jasper report` before. I have no experience on them.

What reporting tool is:

- most suitable for my case
- easiest to learn
- has greater flexibility(maybe add a chart/image in the future...)
- reuse the common thing in each view

Please help. :)

Comment: What's the data source for the reports?

Comment: data source is from a database(postgresql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used ireport 4.5.1 for designing reports and Jasper Reports library for generating reports in all three formats you wanted. I have a good experience using this and I am pretty much sure it will meet your requirements as well. Though it lacks much supporting material.

And its a purely drag and drop interface, reducing you development time. No need to be aware of XML.

Has varied data sources Bean, SQL, HQL, XMl, supports most of the data types you need.

Answering in your requirement:

1. easiest to learn - Yes
2. has greater flexibility(maybe add a chart/image in the future...) - Yes
3. reuse the common thing in each view - Yes

And that is your feasible solution.

Answer (score 2):

DynamicReports which are based on Jasper Report is the good option in this case. It is easy to use with the less stress on coding or XMl generation for the PDF, HTML or Excel generation compaired to Jasper reports.
You can have more details on [DynamicReports here](http://www.dynamicreports.org/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in your question. Jasper is best choice of mine. You can learn quickly or If you are familiar in `XML` and `XSLT`, you can generate report for

1. Pdf - XSLT with FOP
2. Html - XSLT with output method Html
3. CSV - XSLT with plain text output
4. Word & Excel - [Microsoft Office XML formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats)